# MVVM - view displaying information about multiple models

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm

*NB: the question is about server-side web MVC*

In an MVVM(C) design, each View accesses its ViewModel. The ViewModel acts like a kind of bridge for a Model and also contains the state of the View.

I can easily understands this with a simple example, like a view listing users: you would have a UserView which uses a UserViewModel which in turns is an abstraction of a UserModel for the view.

Now imagine a web page that displays information about the users, the products, and the orders, all on the same page. And also a string summarizing the number of elements: "24 users, 8 products, 210 orders".

How, in the above case, can the ViewModel only stick to one Model (assuming you have UserModel, ProductModel, OrderModel) as the view needs to display information about all three models?

***Should a ViewModel include multiple Models and have a 1:n link between ViewModel and Model?***

***Should a ViewModel include other ViewModels and keep a 1:1 link between ViewModel and Model?***

It seems that framweorks like e.g. ZF2 (php) nest viewmodels into a main viewmodel:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#zend-view-quick-start-usage-nesting

PS: this question is about server-side web MVC (as opposed to javascript client-side MVC) and not specific to any programming language (although I am using PHP, so anything c# related like bindings, wpf or other .net components will be hard to grasp).

Answer (score 0):

It does not depend on whether a class acts as a ViewModel or not. There are object oriented principles that requires a low coupling between multiple components. In short, a class should only have a single responsibility and it should know a minimum of other components. As a consequence, it is okay when a ViewModel include other ViewModels. A ViewModel is a usual component, except it is related to a View.

Answer (score 0):

*Should a ViewModel include multiple Models and have a 1:n link between ViewModel and Model?
Should a ViewModel include other ViewModels in order to keep a 1:1 link between ViewModel and Model?*

A ViewModel can include multiple models. A ViewModel can include other ViewModels but not necessarily to maintain a 1:1 link between ViewModel and Model. You can refer to [PresentationModel](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html)